# Disable add button when the input field is empty

Tags: jquery

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ztrpvwx/1/ and in it, i am clicking a button to add a div with some input in it.

I need to notify the user if he or she tries to add another input field without filling an existing input button.

```js
var count = 0;

$("#add_destination").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 78955) + 147;

  if ($('[name="added_dest').is(':empty')) {
    alert('empty detected');
  } else {
    alert('not empty');
  }

  $("#desti_div").append("<div class='tmar'><div class='form-group col-md-6 getspace'><label><i class='gicon fas fa-circle'></i> New Destination</label><input class='form-control input-lg form-field' type='text' id='added_dest" + count + "' name='added_dest' placeholder='New Destinaton' ><a href='' class='gored'><span class='form-control-feedback'></span>Delete</a></div><br/></div>");

});



$(document).on('click', '.gored', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  field_val = $(this).siblings('[name="added_dest"]').val();
  alert(field_val);
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="add_destination" value="add new" />
<div id="desti_div"></div>
```

The code currently is not detecting if the input is empty or not.

Comment: As an experienced SO user you should know that external code references are unwanted for code that can easily be represented as as a StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: There is no element with `[name="added_dest'` in your code and also that selector has a syntax error ( the closing `]` is missing).

Comment: You create the element only **after** you tried to check if it is empty. How can you check before it is there?

Comment: Morning, oh boy, left that out..

Comment: @connexo I think i was so exhausted and sleepy i must have mixed up some code and left out others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you should loop through the fields and check each one for empty string, probably should add a trim in there to ensure no white space

```
 $( "#add_destination" ).on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 78955) + 147;

         let bEmpty = false;
         $('[name="added_dest]').each( function( i, el) {
            if ( el.value == '') {
                bEmpty = true;
                return false; // break out of each
            }
         })

         if ( bEmpty) {
            alert('empty detected');
            return; // don't do it !
         }
         else {
            alert('not empty');
         }


    $("#desti_div").append("<div class='tmar'><div class='form-group col-md-6 getspace'><label><i class='gicon fas fa-circle'></i> New Destination</label><input class='form-control input-lg form-field' type='text' id='added_dest"+count+"' name='added_dest' placeholder='New Destinaton' ><a href='' class='gored'><span class='form-control-feedback'></span>Delete</a></div><br/></div>");

});
```

Comment: actually if you want to disable the button, you will need to add some handling of key events to check that the field is updated and re-enable to button

Comment: Oh never mind,a bug in data- and cordova is making my head spin needlessly fast.